# Getting "keys" from list of dicts

Tags: python

I have the following data:

```
[{'id': ['132605', '132750', '132772', '132773', '133065', '133150', '133185', '133188', '133271', '133298']}, 
 {'number': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']}, 
 {'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']}]
```

What would be the best way to get a list of the keys (as if it was a dict and not an array)? Currently I'm doing:

```
>>> [list(i.keys())[0] for i in e.original_column_data]
['id', 'number', 'id']
```

But that feels a bit hackish

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What is hacky about it? It's a bit inelegant. You just need to do the following:

```
>>> keys = []
>>> data = [{'id': ['132605', '132750', '132772', '132773', '133065', '133150', '133185', '133188', '133271', '133298']},
...  {'number': ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10']},
...  {'id': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']}]
>>> for d in data:
...     keys.extend(d)
...
>>> keys
['id', 'number', 'id']
```

Or if you prefer one-liners:

```
>>> [k for d in data for k in d]
['id', 'number', 'id']
```

Comment: thanks for these answers, these are very helpful. Out of curiosity, why does `keys.extend(d)` only add the key and not the entire dict there? I actually had to test it to make sure it worked because it seemed so counterintuitive. (Unlike `append`)

Comment: `.extend` takes an iterable, and adds all the elements in the iterable to the list. `dict` objects are iterables *over their keys*. If you want an iterable of the values, use `d.values()`, if you want an iterable of the key-value pairs, use `d.items()`

Answer (score 3):

**first way**

iteration on a dictionary gives you its keys, so a simple

```
>>> [key for key in dict]
```

gives you a list of keys and you can get what you want with

```
>>> [key for dict in dict_list for key in dict]
```

**second way**  (only python 2)

use `.key()` (used in your code)
but there is no need to use `list()` (edit: for python 2)
here's what it will look like:

```
>>> [dict.keys()[0] for dict in dict_list]
```

in your code, dictionaries have only one key so these two have the same result.
but **I prefer the first one** since it gives all keys of all the dictionaries

Comment: `dict.keys()[0]` will not work in Python 3

Answer (score 2):

This is simpler and does the same thing:

```
[k for d in e.original_column_data for k in d]
=> ['id', 'number', 'id']
```